# lineTranslateAddress c++ to managed c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, telephony, tapi

I have an application that programatically makes calls to different numbers. The application is written in c# (managed) and I use pInvoke for the c++ TAPI functions. Everything works fine except the fact that I need to convert the phone number to a the dialable format.

To do this conversion, I have to use the C++ function [lineTranslateAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894539.aspx), but from C#. Has anyone used this function from managed code and can provide me some samples or at least explanations.

Maybe some indications how to marshall / nmarshall the last field

> LPLINETRANSLATEOUTPUT
> lpTranslateOutput

I should also mention that the application is for a smart device.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code example, and it works

```
[DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
extern public static int lineTranslateAddress(
    IntPtr hLineApp,
    int dwDeviceID,
    int dwAPIVersion,
    string lpszAddressIn,
    int dwCard,
    int dwTranslateOptions,
    byte[] lpTranslateOutput
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with TAPI in C# on several occasions, and I would strongly suggest using a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) instead of using Platform Invoke. `C:\windows\system32\tapi3.dll` can be added as a project reference and VS will automatically generated an interop assembly that you can use to work with the classes and functions.

This way, you will be able to call the `lineTranslateAddress` function with great ease; via the `ITAddressTranslation` interface.

Note: Even if your TSP only complies with TAPI 2.x, you can still use the functionality in `tapi3.dll` (providing you only call the subset of features supported by TAPI 2)

Comment: does this work also for smart devices? probably not as I can see from the dll path. (I forgot to mention it in the original post)

Comment: It would appear that, unfortunately, the type library can't be used with smart devices.